# C# TCP Sending Generic Objects

Tags: c#, tcp

Ok so I'm working on a simple data entry software for work, using a 3-tier architecture.  What I'm doing is basically using a common dll file to store classes with fields that are filled out when a request to the server is initialized.  I have various user controls set up to take care of different ui forms, this works just fine if I open a connection and send the object directly from the form itself, but that creates a lot of redundant code.  So I thought, lets make a MasterControl and  create a public Connect_To_Server method to send objects over and then process the information sent back.  Only problem is it keeps freezing my server.

Here is the code for my MasterControl:

```
public void Connect_To_Server(object obj)
        {
            using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.20.51.251"), 57657);

                try
                {
                    tcpClient.Connect(endPoint);
                    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

                    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    formatter.Serialize(clientStream, obj);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " - " + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
```

Of course it's going to be a bit more complex later on but just for testing I've made it simple.  Then from one of my ControlForms I create an object from one of the classes listed in the Common.dll, assign it it's values and then pass it to the Connect_To_Server method.

For instance a couple classes from my Common.dll

```
[Serializable]
    public class Switch_Request // Switch class contains an integer describing a boolean request 
    {
        public int switchID { get; set; }
    }

[Serializable]
    public class Send_String_List // Returns a list of strings 
    {
        public int switchID { get; set; }
        public List<string> stringsList { get; set; }
    }
```

On my Server's side:

```
private void bt_StartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Starts the server listening for clients 
{
    Set_String("System: Starting Services.");
    tm_ActiveTime.Start();

    serverListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
    serverThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen_For_Clients));
    serverThread.Start();
}

private void Listen_For_Clients() // Listens for incoming client connections then redirects 
{
    serverListener.Start();
    Set_String("System: Listening for connections...");

    while (true)
    {
        tcpClient = serverListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Handle_Client_Communication));
        clientThread.Start(tcpClient);
    }
}

private void Handle_Client_Communication(object client) // Handles incoming client communications 
{
    TcpClient tempClient = (TcpClient)client;
    clientStream = tempClient.GetStream();

    object sentObjet = formatter.Deserialize(clientStream);
    Type objectType = sentObjet.GetType();

    else if(objectType == typeof(Switch_Request)) // Handle - Switch Request 
    {
        Switch_Request switchRequest = (Switch_Request)sentObjet;
        object obj = new object();

        if (switchRequest.switchID == 1)
        {

        }
        else if (switchRequest.switchID == 2)
        {

        }
        else if (switchRequest.switchID == 3)
        {

        }
        else if (switchRequest.switchID == 4)
        {

        }
        else if (switchRequest.switchID == 5)
        {

        }
        else if (switchRequest.switchID == 6)
        {
            Send_String_List sendStringList = new Send_String_List();
            sendStringList.switchID = 6;
            sendStringList.stringsList = Get_Users();

            obj = sendStringList;
        }
        else if (switchRequest.switchID == 7)
        {

        }
        else if (switchRequest.switchID == 8)
        {

        }
        else if (switchRequest.switchID == 9)
        {

        }
        else if (switchRequest.switchID == 10)
        {

        }

        formatter.Serialize(clientStream, obj);
```

Now I know that the object is being sent and received on the other end, as I set a little text display to popup when the object arrives on the other end, and it displays the correct object and it's type just before the server freezes.  I'm just not sure why it keeps seizing up....

Comment: "it keeps seizing up"... is that all the diagnostic that you are able to offer? Does that mean that you're no longer accepting clients? What does "seize up" mean? Where is your program hanging? In the accept loop?

Comment: Sorry, yah there is an error sending an object back, it says: "IOException was unhandeled: Unable to write data to the transport connection.  An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."